# It's possible set different size a scroll for portrait and landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, xcode5, scrollview

It's possible set different size a scroll for portrait and landscape orientation?
Example: Portrait orientation: x500 y568
         Landscape orientation: x568 y320

## Home.h

@interface Home : UIViewController {

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollerHome;
```

}

@end

## Home.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //----------------------------------ScrollView Home---------------------------------------//
  [ScrollerHome setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [ScrollerHome setContentSize:CGSizeMake(815, 610)];

  }

  @end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation ==
 UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{
    //portrait        
    [ScrollerHome setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 568)];
 }
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    //landscape
    [ScrollerHome setContentSize:CGSizeMake(568, 320)];
}
```